# Copy HttpContext request content data to new request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am building a APIGateway proxy for our dotnet core microservices platform.

I used https://medium.com/@mirceaoprea/api-gateway-aspnet-core-a46ef259dc54 as a starting place, this picks up all requests by using

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
{
   // Do things with context
});
```

You have the context for the request to the gateway, but how do I copy over the content data from the gateway request to a new request I am going to make to my API?

I see the ability to set the request content to a HttpContent object:

```
newRequest.Content = new StringContent(requestContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

But I want my application to take file uploads through the gateway, the only way I found to do it is to create a MultipartFormDataContent, but all examples on how to create a MultipartFormDataContent use a IFormFile instead of a HttpContext.

Is there a way to just copy the content on the initial apigateway request to my internal request:

```
using (var newRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(request.Method), serviceUrl))
{
    // Add headers, etc

    newRequest.Content = // TODO: how to get content from HttpContext

    using (var serviceResponse = await new HttpClient().SendAsync(newRequest))
    {
        // handle response
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the proxy middleware for an example on how to do it https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy/blob/10ca6a434a455a4294842c875b96af173a8ca385/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Proxy/ProxyAdvancedExtensions.cs#L41

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`StreamContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.streamcontent?view=netcore-2.1) for this, passing in the `HttpContext.Request.Body` `Stream` as the actual content to use. Here's what that looks like in your example:

```
newRequest.Content = new StreamContent(context.Request.Body);
```

As an aside, make sure that you use a [shared instance of HttpClient](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).